# Rest API - New Shared Access mode - Not able to know which users I can manage if I'm not admin

Tags: docusignapi

Since a few days, the "envelope shared" method is deprecated in favor of the new "shared access" mode in docusign.
I try to integrate this new mode in my application, but I can't find the way to access to the envelope shared in this mode.

### My use case

An admin user "B" create a shared access from him to the user "A". The user "A" is not an admin user.
When I call the API with user "A" and call the resource "shared access", I can't see any informations about the sharing of the user "B" to me (the user "A").

### how the docusign website works to display me the informations

what I found:
the website call a resource:
https://appdemo.docusign.com/api/accounts/xxxx703a26-133a-402b-b770-3ef7e4xxxx/users/xxxx5b82-0ca8-4678-8250-e2364exxx/authorizations/agent?permissions=Send,Manage&active_only=false&start_position=0&count=40
that display the fact that I can manage the user "B". After that the website display the user "B" account/envelope by using the header X-DocuSign-Act-On-Behalf and fill the userId of the user "B"

When a try to use the same entry point from Postman and a valid oauth token I have this message:

```
{
    "errorCode": "API_RESTRICTED",
    "message": "The API function is restricted and not available for general use."
}
```

Otherwise, the usage of "*X-DocuSign-Act-On-Behalf*" seems to work.

### Questions

- How I can access to the account user I can manage if I'm not an admin
  user ?
- Where is the good way to list shared envelopes in the new
  mode (what I try to do seems to be a hack)?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new feature that is currently not open for developers to use. This may be done in the future, but for now you cannot use this capability in your integration.